# Oracle trace requests and parameters

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm having a c# application using EF4 under Oracle and I want to trace the requests made by the Oracle driver.
I read the documentation and I did my registry configuration like this :

TraceLevel : 3 
TraceFileName : C:\MyOracleTrace.log

what I got is a file filled with many informations but the request are written like this :

```
TIME:2017/03/21-16:40:42:170 TID: 3b0  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx():     RetCode=0 Line=210 (f193690)=253310608
TIME:2017/03/21-16:40:42:170 TID: 3b0  OpsSqlPrepare2(): SQL: SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS "C1"
    FROM "Prefix"."Table" "Extent1"
    WHERE ("Extent1"."Col" = :p__linq__0)
)) THEN 1 WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS "C1"
FROM "Prefix"."Table" "Extent2"
WHERE ("Extent2"."Col" = :p__linq__0)
)) THEN 0 END AS "C1"
FROM  ( SELECT 1 FROM DUAL ) "SingleRowTable1"
TIME:2017/03/21-16:40:42:170 TID: 3b0  (ENTRY) OpsPrmAllocOpoPrmCtx()
```

What I want is the request (as shown here) but also the value of the parameters (:p__linq__0 in the example)

any guess of can I retrieve this ? or is it even possible ?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_trace_bind_variable_values.htm

Comment: I search for a solution without having to connect to the DB. Thanks anyway